# Add collaborator to Alexa-hosted CodeCommit git repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, aws-codecommit

I used `ask init --hosted-skill-id=<skill_id>` to pull a local copy of my skill. Running `git remote -v` shows the repository is hosted on AWS CodeCommit at `https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<skill_id>`.

I can't see the CodeCommit repository in my AWS account (when logged in as root user). I also can't see any IAM roles listed in my AWS account. I considered logging in as the `ask_cli_default` profile generated by `ask configure` but it only has an access key and secret; no password.

**Which AWS account holds the Alexa-hosted CodeCommit repositories? Is there any way to grant access to another account?**

---

**Other potentially relevant tidbits**

- Context: Yesterday I created a skill in the Alexa developer console based on a Hello World template. Now I want to share it with a friend so we can develop it together. Ideally we would both be able to push to a shared git repository, build, deploy, and test using the simulator in Alexa developer console.
- `ask --version` = 2.20.0
- I can `git clone` to another local directory using the (generated) username and password from `ask util git-credentials-helper`.
- a question in the AWS forums [Alexa Hosted sets up a CodeCommit repository](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/202024/alexa-hosted-sets-up-a-codecommit-repository.html) -- *unanswered*
- official AWS docs for [setting up cross-account access to CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html) -- Requires access to the CodeCommit repository from AWS console. This is where I want to get to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexa Hosted is hosted in Alexa's AWS account, so it won't show up in your AWS account. Instead, it provides you with a unique (and highly constrained) AWS IAM role within the Alexa Hosted account that is tied to your skill and your Amazon developer account.

What you need to do if you want to bring in other developers is assign them Developer roles on your account so they can access the skill and its resources using their own account.

This is the documentation for adding people to your org's developer account: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/manage-account-and-permissions.html#add_other_users